# LateX on Mac: Texmaker can't find installed package

Tags: package, latex, miktex, texmaker

I have a Mac and just installed LaTeX and the editor Texmaker. To use the ***Arial*** font I installed it via MiKTeX Console. I also found out that by doing so, the files for the installed packages lay here:

"/Users/Mirko/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex"

My problem is that the Editor (TeXMaker) still doesn't find the Arial-Font.

Here is my Code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,openany,11pt,twoside,a4dutch]{report}


\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{csquotes} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{csquotes} % Setzen von Anführungsstrichen

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}
```

and here is the Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `uarial.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

But the folder arial and the file arial.sty are in the above mentioned folder.

In the MikTeX-Console I already entered the folder to **Directories > Settings**

I thankful for every help!

Thanks and greetings!

Here is the log-file from TexMaker:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.27) 27 OCT 2019 13:34
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
! LaTeX Error: File `uarial.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.5 \usepackage
{csquotes}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
221 strings out of 492616
2365 string characters out of 6129480
60608 words of memory out of 5000000
4231 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
21i,0n,22p,110b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but for mac I would rather use mactex (or texlive) instead of miktex, much more mac user use it and thus it is much better tested

Comment: You seem to have multiple tex installations. The miktex one you updated is not used by texmaker. You can see in the first line of the log file that it is using `TeX Live 2019`

Comment: The easiest way to set a document in arial is to use the font from your mac instead of installing it in latex. Compile the following in xelatex or lualatex (not pdflatex): `% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[openany,11pt,twoside,a4dutch]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for your support! I will check it out. Doesn't it make sense to get rid of the old / other tex installation? Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Being a fan of texlive myself, I would say, yes it makes sense to get rid of miktex :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the first line of the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
```

texmaker is not using the miktex distribution for which you installed the `uarial` package, but a texlive distribution which seems to be also installed on your computer. In the long run it would be best to only have a single tex distribution on your computer to avoid such problems. For mac I would suggest to keep the texlive distribution and get rid of miktex, because texlive is used by most mac users and therefore well tested compared to miktex for mac.

Now you could force texmaker to use your miktex installation by modifying the texmaker preferences, but the easier way to use Arial in your document is to switch from pdflatex to xelatex or lualatex and directly use the arial font installed on your computer

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[openany,11pt,twoside,a4dutch]{report} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Arial} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 

\begin{document} 
This is a test. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I force texmaker to change my preferences?

Comment: @EndLoop In the texmaker preferences, choose the command tab and replace `pdflatex` by the full path, e.g. with texlive on mac it would be something like `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin//pdflatex`. Or add this folder to the `Add to PATH` field